# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, webserver

I'm getting this error when I run the following code. Any help to solve it would be highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlv4D.png)

Error:

Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Restarting with stat

Debugger is active!

Debugger PIN: 269-962-008

gr::log :INFO: audio source - Audio sink arch: alsa

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/fit-pc/my_flask_app/virtualenv/Slider/app.py", line 13, in slide
    return main(slide_val)
  File "/home/fit-pc/my_flask_app/virtualenv/Slider/app.py", line 19, in main
    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
aUaUaUaUaU[Cancelled]
```

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify,request,redirect,url_for
from random import randint
from top_block_22 import top_block_22

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def slide_func():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.form.get('slide_val')
    return main(slide_val)   

def main(slide_val):
    '''Code outside of route'''
    tb = top_block_22()
    tb.start()
    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
    print(samp_rate)
    return(slide_val) # Still need to return or get TypeError   

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Only html needed   -->
  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script>
    var val;
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
      radius: 215,
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
       change: function () {

        var obj1 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
        val = obj1.getValue();
        value: 1
        $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
          slide_val: val
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Main Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##################################################
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Top Block 22
# Generated: Tue Jul 23 15:54:16 2019
##################################################


from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from random import randint
from app import *





class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self):

    #def __init__(self, slide_val):

        #self.slide_val = slide_val


        #gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))



def main(top_block_cls=top_block_22, options=None):


    tb = top_block_22()
    tb.start()
    try:
        raw_input('Press Enter to quit: ')
    except EOFError:
        pass
    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()

    # samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
    # print(samp_rate)
    # return(slide_val) # Still need to return or get TypeError


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: `slide_val` received `None` from the earlier assignment; have you traced that problem to its source?

Comment: @Prune, I updated my posting and added the html script which has the 'slide_val',  would you please take a quick look at it. I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I don't see where you've printed `slide_val` in your posted code.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: @Prune, Sorry about that. I just updated my post with the main code (last piece I have).

Comment: It looks like `slide_val` is an input argument to your main function, but you do not show where you call that function, so it is possible that you are not providing the function with a valid value.

Comment: try calling <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('slide') }}"> in your html before the <div> tag

Comment: @ ,Jmonsky, I do provide the function with the value through the silder widget that I'm using, it ranges between 0 to 100000.

Comment: @AnnaNevison, I did that and still getting the same error.

Comment: Remember that [images of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not as useful as properly formatted text, as they cannot be copy and pasted or read using screen readers.